# Yesterday I was sitting in a Pub which has 50 seats. A question striked me which I am not able to solve.

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

If the maximum number of people the pub can accommodate is 50, it remains open for 9 hours (2 PM to 11 PM), and the Maximum number of people (which is 50) occurs from 6 PM to 7 PM. Taking the distribution is Normal Distribution and the Average sitting time 1 Hour. What is the approximate footfall of the Pub during the entire day?

I can't understand how to approach this problem, or do I miss any necessary information to solve this problem?

Comment: The distribution of what are you taking to be the normal distribution? Note that most of the variables are non-negative, so strictly speaking cannot have the normal distribution.

Comment: @ronno is correct that the Normal distribution is not the right appoach in this case since its support is the whole real line. One approach would be a [birth-death process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth%E2%80%93death_process) with time-dependent (non-homogeneous) Poisson arrival rates.